# Can localstack Kinesis feed to localstack OpenSearch?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, localstack, opensearch

Wanting to use Localstack to emulate my cloud Kinesis Client => Kinesis => ElasticSearch.   Will the Kinesis endpoint deliver data to Elastic, or is just a /dev/null bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

I have this working now.   Installed the same lambda I use in production and enabled OpenSearch in localstack.   In fact, we use the same terraform script for both localstack and AWS.   Cloudpods (localstack pod save/load) is a must since the TF run time can take a while.